# JSONata query to flatten array of arrays

Tags: jsonata

The JSONata doc ["top-level-arrays-nested-arrays-and-array-flattening"](http://docs.jsonata.org/basic.html#top-level-arrays-nested-arrays-and-array-flattening) covers the "flatten" case of an array of objects, each of which contains a property that contains an array value.

However, I have not been able to figure out how to flatten an array of arrays.

Q: What is the JSONata query to flatten an array of arrays?

input

```
    [ [1,2], [], [3] ]
```

desired

```
    [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 7):

I have figured out that flattening an array of arrays can be accomplished by using the `$reduce` function to iteratively apply the `$append` function.

```
    $reduce($, $append)
```

for this simple test case:

```
    $reduce( [ [1,2], [], [3] ], $append)
```

Q: Are there other ways to flatten an array of arrays in JSONata?

Answer (score 5):

In JSONata, iterating over all the elements of an array returns a flattened array of the elements appended together... So it's really as simple as:

```
$.*
```

*Almost looks like an emoji!* ;*)

Technically, you don't even need the `$.` prefix -- but just using the expression `*` doesn't look right to me...

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Looks like you posted this answer while I was composing my more complicated `$reduce($, $append)` method.

Comment: After a few mins of testing I realize that $.* will recursively flatten arrays. The simplified sample data that I used in my original question did not demonstrate this. I actually want to flatten exactly one level of array nesting. Q: How do you recommend flattening exactly one level of array nesting?

Comment: Can you update the question with more representative sample data, and what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Unfortunately, my "reputation" is so poor that I can't even edit my own question. Here is an example ... input data: `[ [1,[2,2]], [], [[3,3],4] ]` should go to `[1,[2,2],[3,3],4]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flatten an array and you're interested in just unique values try this:

```
($distinct($.($distinct($.($distinct($))))))
```