# In JSONata, where is documentation for wildcard * operator in array context?

Tags: jsonata

In [JSONata query to flatten array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570172) SteveR points out that one can use `$.*` to flatten an array.

I have searched through the documentation and found references to wildcard (*) in object context. However I have not found a definition of the behavior of the wildcard (*) operator in array context in JSONata.

The flattening behavior seems to be similar to the flattening of sequences in XQuery.

Q: Where is the behavior of wildcard (*) in array context documented for JSONata?

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard (`*`) is used to select the values of all properties of an object, or array of objects.  The documentation is [here](http://docs.jsonata.org/complex.html#wildcards).

Comment: Apparently, the JSONata doc pages have changed recently. The link to the documentation on the use of the wildcard ( * ) is  now found here: https://docs.jsonata.org/predicate#wildcards