# JSONata to flatten an object with two array values

Tags: arrays, json, flatten, jsonata

I am starting with an object having two values that are arrays. For each one I want to match all non-array values with the array values but with the index values in order e.g, index zero from each array, index 1 from each array, etc.:

The object:

```
{
  "taxedLineItems": [
    {
      "taxCodeNo": [
        "39050",
        "39051"
      ],
      "invoiceLink": "20265654",
      "lineItemNo": 99274137,
      "taxCode": [
        "VAT-A6",
        "Other"
      ]
    },
    {
      "taxCodeNo": [
        "39050",
        "39051"
      ],
      "invoiceLink": "20265654",
      "lineItemNo": 99274137,
      "taxCode": [
        "VAT-A6",
        "Other"
      ]
    },
    {
      "taxCodeNo": [
        "39050",
        "39051"
      ],
      "invoiceLink": "20265656",
      "lineItemNo": 99274142,
      "taxCode": [
        "VAT-A6",
        "Other"
      ]
    },
    {
      "taxCodeNo": [
        "39050",
        "39051"
      ],
      "invoiceLink": "20265656",
      "lineItemNo": 99274142,
      "taxCode": [
        "VAT-A6",
        "Other"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am wanting to "flatten" it so that all the combinations are expressed with no array values - desired output:

```
{
  "taxedLineItems": [
    {
      "taxCodeNo": "39050",
      "invoiceLink": "20265654",
      "lineItemNo": 99274137,
      "taxCode": "VAT-A6"
    },
    {
      "taxCodeNo": "39051",
      "invoiceLink": "20265654",
      "lineItemNo": 99274137,
      "taxCode": "Other"
    },
    {
      "taxCodeNo": "39050",
      "invoiceLink": "20265656",
      "lineItemNo": 99274142,
      "taxCode": "VAT-A6"
    },
    {
      "taxCodeNo": "39051",
      "invoiceLink": "20265656",
      "lineItemNo": 99274142,
      "taxCode": "Other"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried and failed with various $map attempts, etc. One failed attempt:

```
{
"taxedLineItemDetails":
$.taxedLineItems.$map(taxCode, function($v, $i, $a) {
    {
  "invoiceLink":$$.taxedLineItems[$i].invoiceLink,
  "lineItemNo":$$.taxedLineItems[$i].lineItemNo,
  "taxCode":$v  }
})
}
```

Some advice please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is one option:

```
{
    "taxedLineItems":$reduce(
        $map($distinct(taxedLineItems.invoiceLink), function($link, $linkIndex) {
            $map($filter(taxedLineItems, function($v, $i) {$v.invoiceLink = $link}), function($item, $itemIndex) {
                {
                    "taxCodeNo": $item.taxCodeNo[$itemIndex],
                    "invoiceLink": $item.invoiceLink,
                    "lineItemNo": $item.lineItemNo,
                    "taxCode": $item.taxCode[$itemIndex]
                }
            })        
        }), $append)
}
```

With the following parts:
This identifies the unique `invoiceLink`s:

```
$distinct(taxedLineItems.invoiceLink)
```

Mapping over those with:

```
$map($filter(taxedLineItems, function($v, $i) {$v.invoiceLink = $link})...
```

Will allow just dealing with the objects that relate to the `invoiceLink`.

Then the `$itemIndex` is relevant to the arrays for `taxCodeNo` and `taxCode`:

```
{
    "taxCodeNo": $item.taxCodeNo[$itemIndex],
    "invoiceLink": $item.invoiceLink,
    "lineItemNo": $item.lineItemNo,
    "taxCode": $item.taxCode[$itemIndex]
}
```

The wrapper of:

```
$reduce(..., $append)
```

Is per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570172/jsonata-query-to-flatten-array-of-arrays).

Working example:

```js
(async function () {

  const transform = `{
      "taxedLineItems":$reduce(
          $map($distinct(taxedLineItems.invoiceLink), function($link, $linkIndex) {
              $map($filter(taxedLineItems, function($v, $i) {$v.invoiceLink = $link}), function($item, $itemIndex) {
                  {
                      "taxCodeNo": $item.taxCodeNo[$itemIndex],
                      "invoiceLink": $item.invoiceLink,
                      "lineItemNo": $item.lineItemNo,
                      "taxCode": $item.taxCode[$itemIndex]
                  }
              })        
          }), $append)
  }`;

  const result = await jsonata(transform).evaluate(obj);
  
  console.log(result);
  
})()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonata/jsonata.min.js"></script>
<script>
const obj = {
  "taxedLineItems": [
    {
      "taxCodeNo": [
        "39050",
        "39051"
      ],
      "invoiceLink": "20265654",
      "lineItemNo": 99274137,
      "taxCode": [
        "VAT-A6",
        "Other"
      ]
    },
    {
      "taxCodeNo": [
        "39050",
        "39051"
      ],
      "invoiceLink": "20265654",
      "lineItemNo": 99274137,
      "taxCode": [
        "VAT-A6",
        "Other"
      ]
    },
    {
      "taxCodeNo": [
        "39050",
        "39051"
      ],
      "invoiceLink": "20265656",
      "lineItemNo": 99274142,
      "taxCode": [
        "VAT-A6",
        "Other"
      ]
    },
    {
      "taxCodeNo": [
        "39050",
        "39051"
      ],
      "invoiceLink": "20265656",
      "lineItemNo": 99274142,
      "taxCode": [
        "VAT-A6",
        "Other"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly! I had not successfully used $reduce() on my own and did not even know for $distinct()

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that will might help:

```
$distinct(
  $map($.taxedLineItems, function($v, $i, $a) {
    $map($v.taxCode, function($tax, $idx, $array) {
      {
        "taxCodeNo": $v.taxCodeNo[$idx],
        "invoiceLink": $v.invoiceLink,
        "lineItemNo": $v.lineItemNo,
        "taxCode": $tax
      }
    })
  }) ~> $reduce(function($acc, $val, $i, $a) { $append($acc, $val) }, [])
)
```

You can check it out on Stedi's JSONata Playground: https://stedi.link/W2AWzh9

[image]